# Выдает ошибку : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, int

Кусок кода:

```
def parser():
    PAGENATION = ui.lineEdit.text()
    PAGENATION = int(PAGENATION.strip())
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        noutbuki = []
        for page in range(1, PAGENATION):
            print(f'Парсим страницу: {page}')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'page': page})
            noutbuki.extend(get_content(html.text))
            save_doc(noutbuki, CSV)
        pass
    else:
        print('Error')
```

Вот консоль:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Lendor\deskton\project\main.py", 68, in parser() 
    File "C: Users\Lendor\Desktop\project\main.py", line 55, in parser

PAGINATION - int(PAGINATION.strip())

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 ' '
```

Comment: А чего Вы ожидали, приводя к `int` пустую строку?

Comment: я посмотрел все варианты и у меня никак не получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно проверять строку перед `int`, либо оберните try/except. **А лучше** вместо `QLineEdit` для работы с числами **используйте `QSpinBox`**

Для первого варианта:

```
pagenation = ui.lineEdit.text().strip()
if not pagenation:
    print('pagenation must by filled!')
    return
```

А лучше через исключение:

```
try:
    pagenation = int(ui.lineEdit.text().strip())
except ValueError:
    print('pagenation must by filled!')
    return
```

---

**PS.**

Переменными в верхнем регистре принято называть константами, а они объявляются как глобальные и лучше их не переопределять, поэтому в примере используется `pagenation`